# Why virtualenv upgrade would pair with hash -r

Tags: python, bash

I don't understand why below command need to be exercised together.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv
hash -r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it needn't.

Only for those old systems like Ubuntu 12, you need to manually reset $PATH for bash and that is `hash -r` for. I guess you get the command from some out-of-date posts.

`hash` is a bash built-in command. The hash table is a feature of bash that prevents it from having to search $PATH every time you type a command by caching the results in memory